# I want to update all the rows after the first row for each Team

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to update all the rows after the first row for each Team.

**TableName: Test**

```
ID , Team , StartTime, EndTime, TotalTime
1....... A.........18:00.........20:00..........2:00
2....... B.........18:00.........20:00..........2:00
3........A.........18:00.........20:00..........2:00
4........F.........18:00.........20:00..........2:00
5........B.........18:00.........20:00..........2:00

 UPDATE TEST SET StartTime  =  DateAdd(SECOND, - ProjectedTime * 60, EndTime)
```

So here, I want to update row 3 and row  5 (as they are not first records based on team)

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Just for thought, as the answers given already are fine, if a team has 3 records, do you want records #2 and #3 to be altered by the same interval, or the 3rd iteration to be altered in comparison to the 2nd ?

Comment: Yes. So the end date time for the second record, should be used  when altering the 3rd record. this is where i'm still stuck

Comment: Which SqlServer version are you using ?  From SqlServer2012 you have the Lead/Lag window functions which were built for this.  Before that, you need to use Row_Number() to enumerate the records in a CTE and then do an offset join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE for this.

```
   with cte as
    (

    select test.*, row_number() over (partition by team order by ID) as teamRowNum
    from TEST
    )
     UPDATE cte SET StartDate  =  DateAdd(SECOND, - ProjectedTime * 60, EndDate)
    where teamRowNum > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE with `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by team order by id) as seqnum
      from test
     )
update toupdate
    set StartDate = DateAdd(SECOND, - ProjectedTime * 60, EndDate)
    where seqnum > 1;
```