# I want to update all the rows after the first row for each Team. Update StartTime and EndTime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to update all the rows after the first row for each Team.

**TableName: Test**

```
ID , Team , StartTime, EndTime, Estimated Time
1     A      18:00      20:00       1:00
2     B      18:00      20:00       5:00
3     A      18:00      20:00       6:00
4     F      18:00      20:00       0:30
5     B      18:00      20:00       1:00
6     B      18:00      20:00       2:30
7     A      18:00      20:00       1:30

UPDATE #TEST SET EndTime=  DateAdd(SECOND, Estimated Time* 60, StartTime)
UPDATE #TEST SET StartTime=  DateAdd(SECOND, - Estimated Time * 60, EndTime)
```

So here, I want to update row 3 and 7 (for team A) and row  5 and 6 for (team B)  (as they are not first records based on team),

Also the update on the EndTime, for each record should use the calculated startTime + estimated time. and also The Updated Start Time should used the calculated End Time. (while ignoring the first record of that team)

So ideally the result set should be like this...

**TableName: Test**

```
ID , Team , StartTime, EndTime, Estimated Time
1     A      18:00      19:00       1:00
2     B      18:00      23:00       5:00
3     A      19:00      01:00       6:00
4     F      18:00      18:30       0:30
5     B      23:00      00:00       1:00
6     B      23:00      01:30       2:30
7     A      01:00      02:30       1:30
```

How do i achieve this in sql?

Comment: You say `first row after..` but in your sample you change first row for team A. You need to explain better what you need. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: What are `AggregatedTime` and `ProjectedTime`?? And why you lost row 7?

Comment: Thanks for feedback

Comment: I'd add to your question that not only to do you need to update rows that are not first, but you need to update them with values that come from the "previous" row for the team.  Both of these can be handled in a windowing function with a CTE.  Row_Number should work.  Only question is this, is ID your key to knowing which one is first?

Comment: This is an exact repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766349/i-want-to-update-all-the-rows-after-the-first-row-for-each-team

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
UPDATE t SET 
    StartTime=  DateAdd(SECOND, - Estimated Time * 60, EndTime),
    EndTime = DateAdd(SECOND, Estimated Time* 60, StartTime)
FROM #TEST as t
WHERE ID != (SELECT MIN(i.ID) FROM #TEST as i WHERE i.Team = t.Team)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few points about the code below, consider storing the data in the correct datatypes, I'd store the time in an integer field in minutes.  Using the row_number function, you can gain access to the previous row and it's information.  Note, also, that I updated the first row by updating it's endtime to be it's start time plus the estimatedtime.  Then I update the start time of the following rows based on the end time of the previous row.

```
DECLARE @times TABLE
(
    id int
    ,team varchar(5)
    ,starttime time
    ,endtime time
    ,estimatedtimeinminutes int
)

insert into @times values (1, 'A', '18:00', '20:00', 60)
insert into @times values (2, 'B', '18:00', '20:00', 300)
insert into @times values (3, 'A', '18:00', '20:00', 360)
insert into @times values (4, 'F', '18:00', '20:00', 30)
insert into @times values (5, 'B', '18:00', '20:00', 60)
insert into @times values (6, 'B', '18:00', '20:00', 150)
insert into @times values (7, 'A', '18:00', '20:00', 90)

;with cte
as 
(
    select 
        row_number() over (partition by team order by id) rn
        ,team
        ,starttime
        ,endtime
        ,estimatedtimeinminutes
    from 
        @times
)
update CTE
set  
    starttime = 
        case 
            when previousrow.rn is null then cte.starttime -- this is for first rows
            else previousrow.endtime
        end
    ,endtime = 
        case 
            when previousrow.rn is null then dateadd(n, cte.estimatedtimeinminutes, cte.starttime)     -- this is for first rows
            else dateadd(n, cte.estimatedtimeinminutes, previousrow.endtime)  
        end
from cte 
    left join cte previousrow on previousrow.rn = cte.rn - 1


SELECT  *
FROM   @times
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You Can implement by cursor
    --Create table 
    CREATE Table dbo.test 
    (
    ID int, Team varchar(50), StartTime time, EndTime time, [Estimated Time] time
    );
    GO

    --Insert record
    insert into test Select 1,'A','18:00','20:00','1:00'
    insert into test Select 2,'B','18:00','20:00','5:00'
    insert into test Select 3,'A','18:00','20:00','6:00'
    insert into test Select 4,'F','18:00','20:00','0:30'
    insert into test Select 5,'B','18:00','20:00','1:00'
    insert into test Select 6,'B','18:00','20:00','2:30'
    insert into test Select 7,'A','18:00','20:00','1:30'
    Go



    --Implement using Cursor

    DECLARE @Group_SRNo int ,@id int, @Team varchar(50) ,@LastEndTime time

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    Select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY Team,id ) AS Group_SRNo
        ,ID
        ,Team 
    from test 

    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Group_SRNo ,@id , @Team

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   

          If @Group_SRNo=1
          BEGIN
            UPDATE test 
            SET 
                EndTime=Convert(varchar(5),CONVERT(Datetime,StartTime) + CONVERT(Datetime,[Estimated Time]),108)
            Where 
                ID=@id
          END
          ELSE
          BEGIN
                --GET last Update end time
                Select Top 1 @LastEndTime=EndTime  from test where id<@id  AND Team=@Team order by ID desc
                --Update  record 
                UPDATE test
                Set
                    StartTime=@LastEndTime,
                    EndTime=Convert(varchar(5),CONVERT(Datetime,@LastEndTime) + CONVERT(Datetime,[Estimated Time]),108)
                Where 
                    ID=@id
          END


           FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Group_SRNo ,@id , @Team
    END   

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor

    --Check updated record
    Select * from test
```